# X button won't close main navigation, why won't the CSS 'display' change?

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a mobile main navigation that when the menu burger icon is clicked it opens a modal which contains the menu. The modal fills the whole screen and presents the menu. In the top right I have an 'X' that when clicked on is supposed to close the menu, however it will not work. I can open the menu fine, I just can't close it.

When the X is clicked it is supposed to change the css 'display' to equal 'none', but it won't do it. I placed a 'console.log' in the function to see if the clicking was working and it is, just the display won't change.

Any help on why it is not working would be great.

Thanks

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am building this in Wordpress which is why I have the php at the bottom within the html.

```js
let modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
let btn = document.querySelector("#navBtn");
let span = document.querySelector("#close");

btn.onclick = function() {

    modal.style.display = "block";

}

span.onclick = function() {

    modal.style.display = "none";
    console.log("click");

}

window.onclick = function(event) {

    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";

    }

}
```

```css
#modal {

    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    
}

.modal-content {

    background-color: rgba(212, 155, 0, 0.75);
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#close {

    color: #000;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

#close:hover,
#close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-nav-container" id="navBtn">

<a href="javascript:void(0)">

        <div class="nav-icon">

            <div class="burger-icon"></div>
            <div class="burger-icon"></div>
            <div class="burger-icon"></div>

        </div>

    </a>

    <div class="modal" id="modal">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <span id="close">&times;</span>

            <?php wp_nav_menu(

                array(
                    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                    'container'       => 'nav',
                    'container_class' => 'primary-nav',
                    'menu_class'      => 'navbar',
                    'menu_id'         => 'navbar',
                )

            ); ?>    

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
span.onclick = function(event) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    // console.log("click");
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Adding the `stopPropagation();` helps making the "click" event not to propagate down to your `#btn`, because `#span` is placed inside `#btn` and clicking `#span` means you're clicking the `#btn` as well

Apologize for not being able to explain more in-depth on how it works though as I am bad at explaining things, but you can refer to these. They explains the function really well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp

Comment: That worked! Thank you :) I'll read about propagation now.